# Enable Autocomplete with snippet for If/For etc

Tags: autocomplete, editor, code-snippets, adobe-brackets

I have started using the Brackets editor, but I couldn`t find a way to have syntax autocompletion. I want something like in the Sublime or Atom editor after typing "if" and double tab it shows snippets. How do I enable it in Bracket?

```
if (condition) {
    # code...
}
```

Comment: You have to install the relevant snippets package for the language.

Answer (score 0):

The autocomplete is a feature depending on the language you're using, and brackets does not provide it natively except for a few languages.

For example, if you're looking for php autocompletion, search "php" in the extensions menu, and you should find a lot of them.